# RecyclerView crashs in API 28 when ArrayList is filled with datas, in API 33 not

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview

## Kotlin: RecyclerView crashs in API 30 (also in 26 and 28) when ArrayList is filled with datas, in API 33 not.

What is wrong? Although minSdk 26 is specified in Android Studio the app crashes in API 30 (26, 28) but not in API 33.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_klassenliste"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_klassenliste.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral95">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvKlassenname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package de.dr_wo.kompass.test

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import de.dr_wo.kompass.test.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var b: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        b = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(b.root)

        b.rvKlassenliste.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val klassenListe = ArrayList<String>()

//        klassenListe.add("470") // when filling ArrayList whit datas the app crashes
//        klassenListe.add("420")
//        klassenListe.add("")

        val klassenlistenAdapter = KlassenlistenAdapter(klassenListe)
        b.rvKlassenliste.adapter =  klassenlistenAdapter

    }
}
```

Bootsklasse.kt

```
package de.dr_wo.kompass.test

data class Bootsklasse (val name:String, val startgruppe:Int)
```

KlassenlistenAdapter.kt

```
package de.dr_wo.kompass.test

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.TextureView
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import de.dr_wo.kompass.test.databinding.ItemKlassenlisteBinding


class KlassenlistenAdapter (private var klassenListe: ArrayList<String>?)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<KlassenlistenAdapter.KlassenlistenViewHolder>(){


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): KlassenlistenViewHolder {
        val itemBinding = ItemKlassenlisteBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent, false)
        return KlassenlistenViewHolder(itemBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: KlassenlistenViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val bootsklasse: String = klassenListe?.get(position) ?: ""
        holder.myTxtItem.text = bootsklasse
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = klassenListe!!.size


    inner class KlassenlistenViewHolder(private val itemBinding: ItemKlassenlisteBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
        val myTxtItem: TextView = itemBinding.tvKlassenname
    }
}
```

```
2023-05-22 12:24:03.252 29391-29391 AndroidRuntime          de.dr_wo.kompass.test                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: de.dr_wo.kompass.test, PID: 29391
                                                                                                    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:686)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:829)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:531)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461)
                                                                                                        at de.dr_wo.kompass.test.databinding.ItemKlassenlisteBinding.inflate(ItemKlassenlisteBinding.java:45)
                                                                                                        at de.dr_wo.kompass.test.KlassenlistenAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(KlassenlistenAdapter.kt:16)
                                                                                                        at de.dr_wo.kompass.test.KlassenlistenAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(KlassenlistenAdapter.kt:11)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1085)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3456)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2910)
2023-05-22 12:24:03.257 29391-29391 AndroidRuntime          de.dr_wo.kompass.test                E      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1958)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8636)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:988)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:765)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:700)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:967)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f0501ac
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f0501ac
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName(ResourcesImpl.java:267)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:831)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:677)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:912)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:955)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5449)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:660)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:656)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:652)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:587)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:686)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:829)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:531)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461)
                                                                                                        at de.dr_wo.kompass.test.databinding.ItemKlassenlisteBinding.inflate(ItemKlassenlisteBinding.java:45)
                                                                                                        at de.dr_wo.kompass.test.KlassenlistenAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(KlassenlistenAdapter.kt:16)
                                                                                                        at de.dr_wo.kompass.test.KlassenlistenAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(KlassenlistenAdapter.kt:11)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
2023-05-22 12:24:03.259 29391-29391 AndroidRuntime          de.dr_wo.kompass.test                E      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1085)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22417)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3456)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2910)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1958)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8636)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:988)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:765)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:700)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:967)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

This code should also run in devices with API 26. What have I ignored?

Comment: Post the stacktrace for the crash you're getting. Also which API is crashing, 28 or 30?

Comment: 28 and 30, both are crashing. Maybe some others too. I could not edit my text.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says it's failing to inflate `item_klassenliste.xml` at *line 9*, which is the line with the dynamic colour reference. I don't know much about that, besides the fact it was introduced with Android 12 (*API 31*). I can't even find a solid official guide on how you're supposed to use it (from a quick search at least), just advice that says you need to create a separate `colors.xml` for APIs below 31, since they don't have access to the dynamic colour references.

The way you'd do that is by creating a separate `values-31` resource folder, and adding a `colors.xml` file in there with a reference to your dynamic colours. Your `colors.xml` in the plain `values` folder would have static colour references instead, that the earlier APIs can use. Since the system is going to pick which `colors.xml` to use based on API, your `color` resources need to have the same name in both files - so instead of this:

```
android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral95"
```

you'd need something like this

```
android:background="@color/list_colour"
```

And then in the two `colors.xml` files:

```
// values-31/colors.xml
<?xml version=”1.0" encoding=”utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name=”list_colour">@color/material_dynamic_neutral95</color>
    ...
```

```
// values/colors.xml
<?xml version=”1.0" encoding=”utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name=”list_colour">@color/some_other_colour</color>
    ...
```

That way for lower APIs, it safely falls back to another colour definition

---

I don't know if that's what you need to do, I have no experience with this, and a lot of the similar questions and answers are from a couple of years ago - but it sure looks like that's where your problem is coming from, and why it's only affecting stuff on APIs below 31. Other stuff you can try:

- make sure your `compileSdkVersion` is as high as possible, I think 33 is still current. The linter should warn you if there's a higher version you should be using.
- make sure you're using the newest version of the material library (whatever track you're on - I'm not saying move from stable to alpha, unless you have a very good specific reason to)
- check you're following all the practices laid out in [the documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md#using-dynamic-colors)

Hope that helps you solve things! Usually I'll try to research stuff a bit so I can give a more concrete answer, but it really looks like they're making things hard work with this one. Maybe someone else with experience can chime in with advice too.

Comment: Thank you very much! I deleted line 9 in item_klassenliste.xml out. And now the app also runs on the older devices (emulators).
The code here is just an excerpt from an app that should also run on older devices. The background color is initially unimportant.